# How to get innerHTML of a node using scrapy Selector?

Tags: python, html, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

Suppose there are some html fragments like:

```
<a>
   text in a
   <b>text in b</b>
   <c>text in c</c>
</a>
<a>
   <b>text in b</b>
   text in a
   <c>text in c</c>
</a>
```

In which I want to extract texts within tag  but excluding those   tags while keeping their text, for instance, the content I want to extract above would be like "text in a text in b text in c" and "text in b text in a text inc". Now I could get the  nodes using scrapy Selector css() function, then how could I proceed these nodes to get what I want? Any idea would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what I managed to do:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

sel = Selector(text = html_string)

for node in sel.css('a *::text'):
    print node.extract()
```

Assuming that `html_string` is a variable holding the html in your question, this code produces the following output:

```
   text in a

text in b


text in c




text in b

   text in a

text in c
```

The selector `a *::text()` matches all the text nodes which are descendents of `a` nodes.

Comment: This is great, but I managed to make it by sel.css("a").extract() and then using regex to exclude those html tags

Comment: @kuixiong Great! Note that parsing HTML with regex is generally [not considered a good practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/390819). If you control that HTML and it is simple enough, go ahead and use regex. Otherwise, consider relying on specialized tools.

Comment: The solution collects the text, not the innerHTML.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [XPath's `string()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) function on the elements you select:

```
$ python
>>> import scrapy
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""<a>
...    text in a
...    <b>text in b</b>
...    <c>text in c</c>
... </a>
... <a>
...    <b>text in b</b>
...    text in a
...    <c>text in c</c>
... </a>""", type="html")
>>> for link in selector.css('a'):
...     print link.xpath('string(.)').extract()
... 
[u'\n   text in a\n   text in b\n   text in c\n']
[u'\n   text in b\n   text in a\n   text in c\n']
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
response.xpath('//a/node()').extract()
```

Comment: This is the best and safest solution.

Answer (score 0):

in scrapy 1.5, you can use `/*` to get innerhtml.
example:

```
content = response.xpath('//div[@class="viewbox"]/div[@class="content"]/*').extract_first()
```

Comment: This will only extract the first node in .content, use extract() with a ''.join to get the full innerhtml as a string.