# Scrapy Ignore values after <br> tag

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

**HTML:**

```
<span class="number"> - Sep 15, 1991<br><strong>Some Number: </strong>123, 123, 145</span>
```

**Scrapy:**

```
 samples = response.css('ul li.somthing')
    for sample in samples:
        loader = ItemLoader(item=CatelogItem(), selector=sample)
        loader.add_css('some', 'span.number::text')
        yield loader.load_item()
```

**Item.py**

```
some = Field(
    input_processor=MapCompose(str.strip),
    output_processor=Join()
)
```

**Result**

```
- Sep 15, 1991
```

**Expected**

```
- Sep 15, 1991 Some Number: 123, 123, 145
```

Why is this behavior? how do i get the full value loaded in itemloader?

Comment: you mean , loader.add_css('some', 'span.number::innerHtml') result is: The pseudo-element ::innerhtml is unknown

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658047/how-to-get-innerhtml-of-a-node-using-scrapy-selector

Comment: Yep.. Thanks a lot. that works like charm . Fix: loader.add_css('some', 'span.number *::text')

Comment: I am just going to put that down and upvote and check mark the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed to grab all the innerhtml instead of text which includes all of it's nested components.

```
loader.add_css('some', 'span.number *::text')
```